# How to get xcode running in windows?

Tags: xcode, windows, vmware

I recently download latest version of xcode which happened to be in xif format and is unrecognised in windows 10. How can I get to run it on Windows when i cant find proper macOS image for vmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. 
xcode is made specifically for macOS. unless you'll get a macOS hacked image to run in vmware\virtualbox there's no way to run it.

Comment: The problem is that i am unable to find such an image easily. Many a times i have ended up downloading a corrupt vmdk file.

Answer (score 0):

Given, you have setup the vm for OSX or Apple(MAcOS X) 32bit ISO.
Set Up user to have proper root credentials.

1. Go To Official Apple AppStore from Start screen
2. Sign In with apple ID
3. Get Xcode From AppStore and install with root credentials,given earlier.

Hope it helps!!